# SP2013 : CAML query for managed metadata columns for multiple items selected ?

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata, caml

How to write a caml query to fetch data from a managed metadata column ? I have written caml query which works fine for data matching to "Business" .

How do my query return results if the data is matching "Business" and "Corporate".

```
<Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Org\' /><Value Type=\'TaxonomyFieldType\'> Business</Value></Eq>
```

Comment: try this one <Eq><FieldRef Name=\'Org\' /><Value Type=\'TaxonomyFieldType\'> Business</Value><Value Type=\'TaxonomyFieldType\'> Corporate</Value></Eq>